# Запуск npm скрипта из JS файла

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Возможно ли запустить npm скрипт из JS файла(NODE JS, локально)? Если да, то как это сделать? Также интересует вопрос создания программы, которая смогла бы их запускать.

Comment: Я не понял сначала. Сорян. Если не ошибаюсь, то [вот](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) что тебе нужно. Я сейчас живой пример не приведу, на прошлой работе эту штуку юзали активно, но кода под рукой нет.

Comment: @AlexSazonov спасибо, это как раз то, что мне надо